# erlang:now() deprecated in v18, what's the best transition

Tags: elixir

In a package for a [MongoDB driver](https://github.com/checkiz/elixir-mongo), I needed a function to generate a unique document ID.

This function uses `:erlang.now()` that is deprecated in v18

I look for help on how to migrate but no success.

My actual code (shortened):

```
defmodule MyModule_v17 do
  use Bitwise, only_operators: true
  def gen_trans_prefix do
    {gs, s, ms} = :erlang.now
    (gs * 1000000000000 + s * 1000000 + ms) &&& 281474976710655
  end
end
```

best I came up with:

```
defmodule MyModule_v18 do
  use Bitwise, only_operators: true
  Kernel.if Keyword.get(:erlang.module_info, :exports) |> Enum.any?(fn({:system_time, 1}) -> true; (_) -> false end) do
    def gen_trans_prefix do
      :erlang.system_time(:micro_seconds) &&& 281474976710655
    end
  else
    def gen_trans_prefix do
      {gs, s, ms} = :erlang.now
      (gs * 1000000000000 + s * 1000000 + ms) &&& 281474976710655
    end
  end
end
```

It does the job, but I don't feel it's the best way.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To support both OTP 17 and 18 (and beyond) at the same time, you'll need to detect the OTP version at compile time.  Here is an example from the [rebar.config for the lftpc project](https://github.com/potatosalad/lftpc/blob/1.0.5/rebar.config#L4):

```
{erl_opts, [
    {platform_define, "(?=^[0-9]+)(?!^17$)", time_correction}
]}.
```

This regular expression check works because the release of OTP 17 marked the use of [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) (or close to it), so anything less than OTP 17 has a version number that starts with R (like R16).

Then, in your Erlang code you can do something like [this](https://github.com/potatosalad/lftpc/blob/1.0.5/src/lftpc.erl#L952-L958):

```
-ifdef(time_correction).
gen_trans_prefix() ->
    {GS, S, MS} = erlang:timestamp(),
    (GS * 1000000000000 + S * 1000000 + MS) band 281474976710655.
-else.
gen_trans_prefix() ->
    {GS, S, MS} = erlang:now(),
    (GS * 1000000000000 + S * 1000000 + MS) band 281474976710655.
-endif.
```

If you're using mix, you can define the [`erlc_options`](https://github.com/potatosalad/erlang-jose/blob/1.4.2/mix.exs#L8) as done in the [mix.exs for the jose project](https://github.com/potatosalad/erlang-jose/blob/1.4.2/mix.exs#L43-L56):

```
def erlc_options do
  extra_options = try do
    case :erlang.list_to_integer(:erlang.system_info(:otp_release)) do
      v when v >= 18 ->
        [{:d, :time_correction}]
      _ ->
        []
    end
  catch
    _ ->
      []
  end
  extra_options
end
```

The `erlc_options` can be referenced by Erlang or Elixir code for the project (similar to the solution you mentioned in your question):

```
defmodule MyModule do
  use Bitwise, only_operators: true
  if Enum.member?(Mix.Project.get!.project[:erlc_options] || [], {:d, :time_correction}) do
    def gen_trans_prefix do
      {gs, s, ms} = :erlang.timestamp
      (gs * 1000000000000 + s * 1000000 + ms) &&& 281474976710655
    end
  else
    def gen_trans_prefix do
      {gs, s, ms} = :erlang.now
      (gs * 1000000000000 + s * 1000000 + ms) &&& 281474976710655
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you for your post, I like the way you handled it. I create a repo [jerp/now](https://github.com/jerp/now) where I put what I did in the end. It's close to your answer

Comment: Also, on another matter, I glad to find out about erlang-jose. I do sign message using a port on OpenSSL, I'll look at your project in the near future.

Answer (score 7):

This is already covered in the ["Time and Time Correction in Erlang" documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html) and also in the ["Time Goes On" postscript](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/time) to the wonderful ["Learn You Some Erlang" book](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content).

Comment: Great reference indeed. It helps. But the question was more about how to manage the transition. In "Learn You Some Erlang", the author points to [okeuday/uuid](https://github.com/okeuday/uuid) that implements a solution similar to @potatosalad. Looking at both options right now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
erlang:timestamp()
```

which is an alternative to erlang:now() in erlang 18

check this:
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#timestamp-0

Comment: thank you but the question is not how to replace erlang.now() but what's the best transition for a package that should work in both version v17 and v18. `erlang:timestamp()` does not exist in v17

Comment: It's not a suitable replacement either anyway, as erlang:timestamp/0 is not guaranteed to be unique like erlang:now/0 is, an important feature of the question.

Answer (score 2):

If `erlang:now()` is *deprecated* but not *removed* in Erlang 18 then I'd leave the code alone.

This is my reasoning: If you build new code, build it for Erlang 18 and later and use `erlang:timestamp()`. That is, if you build new code will you need it to be able to run on both Erlang 17 and Erlang 18?  Chances are if it's new code you can just stipulate that it's only run on 18. And if you're maintaining code and `erlang:now()` still works in 18, then what's the issue?

Remember that deprecated is not the same as removed.  It just means you should avoid using it for new work.

Comment: Well, although this is a very reasonable option, I get an epidermic reaction when I see `warning erlang:now/0 deprecated BIF`. I guess anyone using this library would feel the same. Especially when looking up at the erlang doc saying in bold **This function is deprecated! Do not use it!**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
os:timestamp()
```

which is available in both v17 and v18.

See also: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html